# Ubuntu 22.04 - newly created screen resolution not selectable

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have the following combination:

- Processor Intel® Core™ i7-7500U
- Display S3422DWG

The screen is attached with HDMI.
The maximal achievable resolution with this combination is 3440 x 1440 @ 24Hz.
This resolution works in the windows running in another partition.

So after the update to ubuntu 22.04, the resolution cannot be changed with xrandr.

Here's what I did:

```
cvt 3440 1440 24

return

# 3440x1440 23.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 35.08 kHz; pclk: 153.25 MHz
Modeline "3440x1440_24.00"  153.25  3440 3560 3904 4368  1440 1443 1453 1463 -hsync +vsync
```

then I checked the connected displays

```
xrandr --listactivemonitors

return

0: +*XWAYLAND0 1920/800x1080/330+0+0  XWAYLAND0
```

The screen I'd like to change is the XWAYLAND0 (the primary display)

So I added a new mode

```
xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_24.00"  153.25  3440 3560 3904 4368  1440 1443 1453 1463 -hsync +vsync
```

No return - so I assume everything worked fine.

Then I added the new mode to my display.

```
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "3440x1440_24.00"
```

No return - so I assume everything worked fine.

Then I tried to select the newly created resolution, but it is not displayed in the settings list.

[image: Printscren of the display settings]

How can I check what went wrong.
Is there some kind of log I could check?
Why is the newly added resolution not displayed?

Comment: so you are using Wayland, and the "xwayland" monitor is X running *within* wayland (for specific applications that need xorg). xrandr only works for xorg, not wayland. You can try switching to xorg, and then you should be able to use xrandr to set resolutions.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that. Thanks.
I switched to xorg at the login screen and it worked directly as expected.
Quite confusing.

Comment: the 'x' in 'xrandr' indicates that it only works for xorg, same with 'xinput' and things like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just upgraded from ubuntu 20.04 and the script I made to control brightness and to adjust the resolution of my second monitor stop working.

The problem relays on the use of wayland at the login. so to turn back to Xorg in the login screen of ubuntu you have to click in the little gear on the bottom right corner and then select Xorg. after that everything worked as usual.

Comment: You saved my life.