# Old Mac not recognizing external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, 22.04, macbook-pro

I installed 22.04 on an old MacBookPro9,2 (mid 2012), dual boot. I have included third-part drives.
My external display (old Lenovo, full HD) is either blank or only visible at low resolution. The same monitor works in full HD with 22.04 installed on a Lenovo.
The Settings' About-menu recognizes a "Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)".
I should probably install a new driver, but I am a newbie and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `cat /etc/default/grub` and let us know if the line GRUB_GFXMODE= is has#ed out.

Comment: Yes! It says
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

Comment: Do you know how to edit your grub? You can remove the # and give that a go.

Comment: I did 
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
and reinstated 
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480 

The second monitor shows up consistently now, but only offers 1024 X 768 (3:4)

Comment: I tried to change the resolution of my external monitor following this guide
https://igor.technology/solving-ubuntu-2004lts-external-monitor-resolution-problems/
I can give the commands but cannot see the new resolution in the settings

Comment: It seems a problem with the use of WAYLAND0 at the login. see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420541/ubuntu-22-04-newly-created-screen-resolution-not-selectable I chose Xorg in the login screen and followed this guide:
https://igor.technology/solving-ubuntu-2004lts-external-monitor-resolution-problems/